# Is it possible to get multiple reports at a time with normal single report

Tags: asp.net, .net, reportviewer

I am using report viewer (.rdlc report) to print a normal sales receipt in ASP.net project.

I used text boxes in my report to show data. If I send a single receipt details to the report it prints it well and it is working normally.

My question is, what do I need to do if I want to print 2 or more than 1 receipts with same functionality or with same report. In other words, if I send 10 receipt IDs to the form it should result in a report with those number of prints or receipts in the report viewer.

Is it possible through report viewer, or do I need some other technology?

Comment: you may use `2 reports` to a single report viewer control as well.

Comment: You don't have to add tags to your title. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I generate the datasource with all the information from all receipts.

In .Rdlc I use a row group (`group by IDRECEIPT`).

I put the `Dataset Fields` into a `rectangle` and select the option `add page break after`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a **List** control in your report.

See [Adding a List](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159121%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

You will need to set up your report/DataSet to have a parameter that takes multiple receipt ID values.

The List will repeat for each row in the DataSet, i.e. if there are ten receipts the objects in the List object (textboxes, etc) will repeat for each receipt row.

It will be one report but will have a repeated section for each receipt.